# Self-executing anonymous function: How to open in same tab and sequential?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to be able to open URLs using one tab only, and not in separate tabs.
I have 2 URLs that should open in the same tab. Currently, I get them to open up in 2 separate tabs.

- My self-executing anonymous function:

  (function(){open('https://www.umsatzfinanzierung.org')})();

  (function(){open('mobincube://action/section/Aktiv')})();

The two URLs get opened but in separate tabs!

Also, I cannot open the 2nd URL in the same tab because I would lose the mobile frame environment.

Can some one provide me with a solution to this problem?

Comment: Set `window.location.href` instead of calling `window.open`? Or do you want all the three documents to appear in the same tab at the same time?

Comment: Thanks! It works and gives me an idea how to make it that I don't lose the app frame in android.